# Dynamically update the count of selected CheckBox in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find out a way to update the count of the selected checkboxes in excel using VBA.

[image]

i.e as the user selects the checkbox, the count has to get updated across the relevant filed. For example, If I select first check box ABC/18-49. The count at the top for (18-49) should get updated to 3.

**P.S:** This is how I have created the checkboxes dynamically.

```
Sub Main()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Ws.Range("A:A").Insert
Set WorkRng = Ws.Range("A2:A" & Ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    With Ws.CheckBoxes.Add(Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
        .Characters.Text = "Yes"
    End With
Next
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: One way I can think of is giving the checkboxes relevant names so that you can loop through the checboxes to see which ones are clicked and then count the checked ones with a relevant name. On a separate note, I would have done this using Datavalidation instead of checkboxes...

Comment: Pressing the check boxes, do that trigger events, assigned `Subs`?

Comment: well, I am thinking of it to have an event trigger when a check box is clicked. But, not sure how to implement it in excel/VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

1. Copy the next `Subs` in a standard module and run the first one. It will assign a specific macro to all check boxes from column A:A:

```
Sub AssingMacro()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape, chkB As CheckBox
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet

  For Each s In sh.Shapes
    If left(s.Name, 6) = "Check " And s.TopLeftCell.Column = 1 Then
        s.OnAction = "CheckBoxesHeaven"
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Sub CheckBoxesHeaven()
Dim sh As Worksheet, chB As CheckBox

  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set chB = sh.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
  If chB.Value = 1 Then
    Debug.Print chB.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        If chB.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "18-49" Then
            sh.Range("C3").Value = sh.Range("C3").Value + 1
        ElseIf chB.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "50-64" Then
            sh.Range("C1").Value = sh.Range("C1").Value + 1
        Else
            sh.Range("C2").Value = sh.Range("C2").Value + 1
        End If
  Else
        If chB.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "18-49" Then
            sh.Range("C3").Value = sh.Range("C3").Value - 1
        ElseIf chB.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "50-64" Then
            sh.Range("C1").Value = sh.Range("C1").Value - 1
        Else
            sh.Range("C2").Value = sh.Range("C2").Value - 1
        End If
  End If
End Sub
```

2. Assort the values in range "C1:C3" to match the appropriate check boxes value. In order to automatically do that, please use the next code:

```
Sub ResetCheckBoxesValues()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, chkB As CheckBox, i As Long
   Dim V50_64 As Long, V18_49 As Long, VLess18 As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   For Each chkB In sh.CheckBoxes
        If chkB.TopLeftCell.Column = 1 Then
            Select Case chkB.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                Case "50-64"
                    If chkB.Value = 1 Then V50_64 = V50_64 + 1
                Case "18-49":
                    If chkB.Value = 1 Then V18_49 = V18_49 + 1
                Case "<18":
                    If chkB.Value = 1 Then VLess18 = VLess18 + 1
            End Select
        End If
   Next
   sh.Range("C1:C3").Value = Application.Transpose(Array(V50_64, VLess18, V18_49))
End Sub
```

3. Start playing with check boxes selection. It will add a unit to the appropriate cell if checking and decrease it with a unit in case of unchecking.

Please, test it and send some feedback

Comment: @Pavan Gunda: Where did you copy the `Sub` "CheckBoxesHeaven"? Didn't you do it in a standard module, as I said? But, did you try using these subs in a `.xls` workbook? They are able to work only in a `.xlsm` (macroEnabled workbook...) type.

Comment: @Pavan Gunda: Just curious... Where was the problem?

Comment: I dint tried it in standard module. Hence there was a problem. Later on, I created a standard module and it got worked.

Comment: @Pavan Gunda: This is what I said. It could be placed in the sheet module, too, but on place it in `OnAction` it should be fully qualified. I mean, with the sheet code module in front of the procedure...

Answer (score 0):

It will not be "very" dynamic, make sure to click on a random Excel cell, to make the formula recalculate after updating the check on the checkbox.
But the formula works in Excel, with the checkboxes you have created:

```
Public Function CountCheckBoxes()
        
    Dim chkBox As Shape
    Dim counter As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For Each chkBox In .Shapes
            If InStr(1, chkBox.Name, "Check Box") Then
                If .Shapes(chkBox.Name).OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next chkBox
    End With
    
    CountCheckBoxes = counter
    
End Function
```

Probably you should think about a suitable workaround to avoid `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`, depending on where the code is residing.

Comment: How to add this function in my excel VBA and how to get it triggered after every click?

Comment: @PavanGunda - Put it in a module. Then refer to it like this in Excel - `"=CountCheckBoxes"`, the same way as you write `=SUM(A1:A10)`